# Tableau calculating differences based on dates in the same column

Tags: tableau-desktop

so I have a data set which contains loan information about different facilities. My data set has a column called snap date. I want to observe difference between two snap dates but instead of using quick table calculations which limit what I can do with those calculations I want to do more like put checks on those differences. How do I do that?

I have tried working with quick table calculations but it restricts place checks on those differences in averages based on snap date in different segments but

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an example or describe in more detail what you are trying to do?